# Succeed to connect my WCF service only from local machine unless machine ip address is specified instead of localhost

Tags: c#, wcf

I have `WCF service` that clients connect to this service and do some operations.
This is my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceHostingInWinService.MySampleWCFService">
        <endpoint
          name="ServiceHttpEndPoint"
          address="" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="WCFServiceHostingInWinService.IMySampleWCFService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint
          name="ServiceMexEndPoint"
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.0.192:8733/MySampleWCFService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

This service installed on several machines but on each machine i need to change the  `<add baseAddress="http://192.168.0.192:8733/MySampleWCFService/" />` to the relevant `IP address` in order it to work, when specified `localhost` instead of `Machine IP address` i can connect to my service only from local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 0.0.0.0 on base address, It should work for every network interface on system regardless of the address of it. localhost doesn't work because it call the DNS lookup, which evaluates to 127.0.0.1, that's serve only local.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 on the Client and the service 2 ?

Comment: Only on the service side, the client must have the real IP of where the server is running.